# Alamofire upload progress

Tags: swift, alamofire, alamofire5

I am completely new in Alamofire (and in Swift in general). And I need to get the realtime **upload progress**. How to achieve that?

Here I am uploading multiple PDF documents :

```
AF.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
    for f in files{
        multipartFormData.append(f.data, withName: "files", fileName: f.name, mimeType: "application/pdf")
    }
}, to: "http://localhost:8080/api/v1/documents")
.uploadProgress { progress in
    print("Upload Progress: \(progress.fractionCompleted)")
}
```

Here it only outputs, which is not what I expect

```
Upload Progress: 1.0
```

So is this documentation lying? https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Documentation/Usage.md#upload-progress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your file is too small, try a larger file.